# How to replace url /?/ to /-/ in friendly url liferay 6.2?

Tags: liferay

I'm doing security fix in liferay 6.2 with url /?/ and I want replace /-/
I'm using href from jsp to jsp and passing variables. 
My link web: https://iportal24.vnpttiengiang.vn/chi-tiet-tin/?/Sua-bai-viet-tin-tuc/27593

Link security  :https://iportal24.vnpttiengiang.vn/chi-tiet-tin/-/Sua-bai-viet-tin-tuc/27593

Comment: what do you mean that you want to replace "/?/"? The question mark is a special character in URLs and Liferay does not use it in the path part of friendly URLs OOTB.

Comment: Hi  Miroslav Ligas, thank you anser! 
My problem is, send variable data from JSP to JSP page, my code:

<a onclick="window.location.href ='/detail-vb?DocIdconfig=<%=ngd.getDocumentId() %>';"  style="color:black !important; text-decoration:none; "><%=ngd.getSummary() %></a>

Comment: Hi  Miroslav Ligas, thank you anser! 
My problem is, send variable data from JSP to JSP page, my code:
jsp1:

<a href="/chi-tiet-tin/?/<%=ds_first.getURLarticle()%>/<%=ds_first.getArticleId()%>" ><img  alt="<%=ds_first.getTitle() %>" src="<%=ds_first.getSmallimg()%>" ></a>

jsp2: 

 String url = PortalUtil.getCurrentURL(request); //gett id from jsp1 and substring url

Comment: with url friendly, I'm using config, <instanceable>false</instanceable>, url friendly not woking

Answer (score 1):

You are not using Liferay friendly URL functionality. Also, your code shows that you generating the URLs in an inappropriate way. Please use appropriate taglibs , ... to generate links.

And also use iner portlet comunication for sending parameters between portlets.

Comment: hi Miroslav Ligas,thanks you anser!. But how do I use 
http://sonoivu.loc.vn:8080/chi-tiet-tin/?/Uu-tien-tuyen-thang-hoc-sinh-gioi-hoc-sinh-82-truong-chuyen/448317  , how I replace /?/ to /-/ , thank you so much

Comment: how does the ? come into the link in first place? it seems that you are putting it there manually <a href="/chi-tiet-tin/?/<%=ds_first.getURLarticle()%>/<

Comment: yes, /chi-tiet-tin is page and I have portlet is chitiettin get id from href

Comment: but, if I using config with <instanceable>true</instanceable> ,how using friendly URL when p_p_id=Van_Ban_Config_WAR_Quan_Ly_Van_Ban_21portlet_INSTANCE_nYJ8xBbBon7y, thank you so much!

Comment: file liferay-portlet.xml

<configuration-action-class>com.testportlet.config.MVC.PortletConfigurationAction</configuration-action-class>
  <!-- <struts-path>document_library_display</struts-path> -->
  <friendly-url-mapper-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultFriendlyURLMapper </friendly-url-mapper-class> 
  <friendly-url-mapping>vanban</friendly-url-mapping>
  <friendly-url-routes>com/testportlet/MVC/friendly-url-router.xml</friendly-url-routes> 
  
  
  <instanceable>true</instanceable>

Comment: Please add your Liferay portlet xml and friendly url xml samples into the question. Either way you should use the tags and they will hendle all for you. Construction like "/chi-tiet-tin/?/<%=ds_first.getURLarticle()%>" should never be used. The rule given by JSR is that he URL is not to be created manualy and is the reponsibility of the portal to provide it. What locale do you run liferay under EN?

Comment: with  like "/chi-tiet-tin/?/<%=ds_first.getURLarticle()%>" , I not using  friendly url, Please, how I href from jsp to jsp and send and passing variables ,not using url /?/....,thank you  Miroslav Ligas!!

Comment: have a look here https://github.com/mir333/generic-portlet this is an example how 2 portlets can communicate.

Comment: thank you so much!!!!, 
I will watch  github.com/mir333/generic-portlet

Comment: hi  Miroslav Ligas, in file liferay-portlet.xml i'm set <instanceable>true</instanceable>, so, how I set  friendly url when "p_p_id"  have "INSTANCE_nYJ8xBbBon7y", thank you Miroslav Ligas

Comment: <route>
 
  <pattern>/{Detail_Document_Config}</pattern>
  <generated-parameter name="jspPage">/View_Config/{Detail_Document_Config}.jsp</generated-parameter>
 </route>

Comment: can not  link jsp Detail_Document_Config, return link http://sonoivu.loc.vn:8080/qc-trai/-/vanban_config/Detail_Document_Config?DocIdconfig=528847 but not view detailed content

Comment: it working with <pattern>/{instanceId}/{Detail_Document_Config}</pattern>

Comment: but, I can not send value to jsp if not using ?DocIdconfig=<%=ngd.getDocumentId()%>

Comment: do you need to have the instantiation enabled? if not just put instancaible false. If you have an instanciable portlet you need to always provide a way for the portal to identify what instance you are targeting in the call. As I mentioned previously use the URL tag to generate the links. The URL my look uglier but it will work. The URL format is a Liferay  limitation.

Comment: hi  Miroslav Ligas, I did , thank you so much!!
I using: 
<pattern>/{instanceId}/{Detail_Document_Config}/{DocIdconfig:[^/]+}</pattern>

Comment: Hi   Miroslav Ligas, If T'm using this :link:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8MLB.png

so,how I can friendly url, thank you  Miroslav Ligas!!!